# Abort running WordPress function under certain conditions

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to abort a running WordPress function. When the user deletes a custom post type (in my case, a store), I want to check to see if there are any associated posts with that store. I am running a query and checking to see if there are returned results. If we return 1 or more results, I want to abort the delete and present the user with an error message stating that they must delete the associated post. I am using the action 'before_delete_post'. Here is what I'm going for:

```
if (count($results)==0){
    //delete the data
} else {
    //abort the delete.
}
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: you should try something and let us know if it doesn't work, not ask us how to do your work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using before_delete_post you could have something like this:

```
function prevent_delete_custom_post() {
    if (count($results)==0){
        //delete the data
    } else {
        wp_redirect(admin_url('edit.php')); //here you can try to get the variables that you have in the url to redirect the user to the same place.
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('before_delete_post', 'prevent_delete_custom_post', 1);
```

Remember that 'before_delete_post' action is fired before post metadata is deleted.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/before_delete_post

And 'delete_post' action is fired before and after a post (or page) is deleted from the database.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post

Comment: Thanks, how would I display a message to the user when we redirect them to the edit page to say that the delete wasn't successful?